# Why all coffeescript files always executed all at once Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I've got in the assets folder, different coffeescript files for each model. But they are all executed every time I visit a page, even if it is from a different controller. If I go on /insertion/new I expect that only insertion.coffee is executed, instead all of my .coffee start. How can I launch one at a time?

This is my insertions.coffee

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  if ($('#insertion_book_search'))
    console.log("found")
  console.log($('#insertion_book_search').length)
  console.log($('#insertion_book_title').length)
  $('#insertion_books_subject').parent().hide()
```

That's my static_pages.coffee

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  console.log("Mie cose")
  $('.last_img').on 'load', ->
    natHeight = $(this).get(0).naturalHeight
    natWidth = $(this).get(0).naturalWidth
    if (natWidth > natHeight)
      $(this).css( 'width','100%')
    else
      $(this).css( 'height','100%')
```

What I'd like to achive is that when I'm using the insertion controller, it loads only the insertion.coffee, and when I'm using the static pages controller it loads only the static_pages.coffee. 
From what I understand, when I add the line `// require_tree .` to the `/app/assets/javascript/application.js` all my coffee are loaded in all my views.

If I remove the require tree and I try to add them with <%= javascript_include_tag ..%> I need to have a .js file and not a coffee. Is possible to load coffee files?

Comment: Post two separate examples of your coffeescript assets. I'm willing to bet that you're tying them to the same event, which is why they both run. Keep in mind that you can put coffeescript/js in different files, but they're all compiled into one monolithic file under the covers. The different file names are to help you organize scripts -- they're not namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make selection by using coffeescript OOP method, below is the detail and some code for your requirement

- I suggest you to use coffee with class method and then check each page with event turbolinks:load
- you can check which page with name of 
  controller and the the method for example $(".purchase_requests.new")[0] meaning the controller is purchase_requests and the method new
- also I suggest you to read brandon hilkert blog for some additional reference below is [the link](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/organizing-javascript-in-rails-application-with-turbolinks/)

sample coffeescript with check each page load

```
class App.PurchaseRequest

  renderYourJavascript: ->
    console.log "purchase request js"

$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  if $(".purchase_requests.new")[0] || $(".purchase_requests.edit")[0]  
    purchase_request = new App.PurchaseRequest
    purchase_request.renderYourJavascript()
```

as you can see from my code above you can split by checking $(".controllers.action")[0]

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about Rails [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). All your scripts are getting executed because most likely  you have `//= require_tree .` [directive](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) in your `application.js` manifest file.

If you want to manually specify JS-files for actions, you should reorganize your manifest (at least remove `//= require_tree .` from it), and then you can use `javascript_include_tag` to include JS manually. More info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets).

**NOTE:** If you include your files manually, without mentioning them in manifest, you also should add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( path/to/file )` to your `config/initializers/assets.rb` to get it precompiled. Otherwise you will get an exception that will tell you to do it. More of it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets).

> If I remove the require tree and I try to add them with <%= javascript_include_tag ..%> I need to have a .js file and not a coffee. Is possible to load coffee files?

Your coffeescript files are getting precompiled to JS anyway. All you need is to specify file name without extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate you Coffeescript logic in classes and then initialize the class in the views you actually need that logic to be called.

So your coffee file would look something like this:

```
class YourClass

   constructor: () ->
     # Anything here will be called when this object is instantiated
     @firstMethod()
     @secondMethod()

  firstMethod: () ->
    $('#some-element').click () ->
      alert('hello world')

  secondMethod: () ->
    console.log('second method triggered!')


window.YourClass = YourClass
```

And then whenever you need this logic in a specific view, you can actually just initialize this object:

```
<script>
  var yourClass = new YourClass();
</script>
```

You can even call specific methods, by moving them out of the constructor method and explicitly calling them in your view:

```
<script>
  var yourClass = new YourClass();
  yourClass.methodNotInConstructor();
</script>
```